What is the equivalent of the code written by jetty.continuation in Jakarta.server.AsyncContext?
I want to upgrade my project from jetty 9 to 12.
Since the jetty.continuation is deprecated, I want to replace the following code snippet using AsyncContext class.
        Continuation cont = ContinuationSupport.getContinuation(request);
         .
         .
         .
        cont.setTimeout(suspendMs);
        cont.suspend();

what is the code equivalent?
which method does implement "suspend" in AsyncContext class?

The best source of advice for moving from Jetty Continuations (deprecated in Jetty 8 btw, removed in Jetty 10), is to look at the Servlet3Continuations.java source in the jetty-9.4.x branch.
Methods like suspend() and resume() are not a 1::1 method call on AsyncContext, but in fact multiple method calls.
Continuation to AsyncContext

Continuation.setTimeout(long) ::
AsyncContext.setTimeout(long);


Continuation.suspend() ::
HttpServletRequest.startAsync();
HttpServletRequest.setTimeout(...);
HttpServletRequest.addListener(AsyncListener); // handles onTimeout and onComplete


Continuation.suspend(ServletResponse response) ::
HttpServletRequest.startAsync(request, response);
HttpServletRequest.setTimeout(...);
HttpServletRequest.addListener(AsyncListener); // handles onTimeout and onComplete


Continuation.resume() ::
AsyncContext.dispatch();


Continuation.complete() ::
AsyncContext.complete();


Continuation.isSuspended() ::
HttpServletRequest.isAsyncStarted();


Continuation.isResumed() ::
// no servlet API for this


Continuation.isExpired() ::
// no servlet API for this


Continuation.isInitial() ::
if (HttpServletRequest.getDispatcherType() != DispatcherType.ASYNC) {
  // possibly the initial request
  // note, this could be a REQUEST / INCLUDE / FORWARD / ERROR dispatch
}


Continuation.isResponseWrapped() ::
// no servlet API for this


Continuation.getServletResponse() ::
AsyncContext.getRequest();
AsyncContext.getResponse();


Continuation.addContinuationListener(ContinuationListener) ::
AsyncContext.addListener(AsyncListener);


Continuation.setAttribute(String, Object) ::
HttpServletRequest.setAttribute(String, Object);


Continuation.getAttribute(String) ::
HttpServletRequest.getAttribute(String);


Continuation.removeAttribute(String) ::
HttpServletRequest.removeAttribute(String);


Continuation.undispatch() ::
// no servlet API for this




Thank you very much for your reply. Continuation.undispatch() method is used in my code. What code should I replace it with? Can you explain what exactly this method does so that I can implement it myself? @Joakim Erdfelt

See the linked Servlet3Continuation.java, you'll see that undispatch() does nothing more than throw an Exception in the face of the caller, it does not change the state of the async in any way.  At this point you should abandon ALL of your Continuations based logic and read up on how the standard Servlet AsyncContext operates and use that, don't try to just "convert" this code, do it right.
